# Systems for inter-human touch classification?

Tags: reference-request, computer-vision

I'm trying to find any publications involving a system that can classify if there is physical contact in a video. Ideally, if the physical contact is brief, it would also be beneficial to classify. However, despite this clearly defined problem, I've been unable to find any mention of this in the literature. I am able to find many references for human action recognition, but no such fine-grained distinction of physical contact.

Do any systems exist that move towards these goals?